Config for template path switch
I seem to remember in a multisite Craft 3 setup I could specify the root template path for a site.
Is this still possible? I have scoured the Craft 5 docs and can't see it mentioned in the general config settings, only in the custom plugin docs.

In my web/index.php I use this on craft 4
define('CRAFT_TEMPLATES_PATH', "path/to/templates");

I will test on craft 5 shortly

Confirming it does indeed still work in v5
